# How to get specific data from table1, use it in table2

Tags: php, database, mysqli, while-loop

I'm trying to get specific rows in table 1 (stellingen). I want to store these rows to specify the rows im interested in for the second table (stelling). So lets say table 1 has 5 rows where stelling ID matches REGIOID = 5. These IDS from stelling ID I want to use to fetch the data from the second table. see the code to see what I tried. I'm not managing to find a way in order too make this happen.

So maybe too be clearer because people always say im not clear:
There are two tables. they both have a matching column. Im trying to tell the second table I want data but only if it matches the data of the first table. Like a branch of a tree. Then, I want to output some data that's in the second table.

I've tried something like this before:

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  table2 
LEFT JOIN 
  table1 ON 
    table1.ID = table2.table1_id
```

I've tried to  create a while loop to get the data before(after the first if statement and the last += was for the variable $amountofstellinge):

```
    $amountOfStellinge = 0;
    while ($amountOfStellinge<5){
        mysqli_data_seek($result, $amountOfStellinge);
```

Here is the code what it looks like now, its wrong, i've been messing with t a lot, but maybe it shows you what I'm trying to achieve better.

```
if($result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM stellingen WHERE REGIOID=1;")) {

        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

        $stellingid= $row["Stelling_ID"];
        //checking.. and the output is obviously not what I want in my next query
        printf($stellingid);

    //defining the variable
        $Timer=0;

$sql1="SELECT * FROM stelling WHERE stelling_iD=$stellingid ORDER BY Timer DESC;";
$records2 =  mysqli_query($con, $sql1);
$recordscheck = mysqli_num_rows($records2);
//max 5 data
if ($recordscheck < 5){
    while ($stelling = mysqli_fetch_assoc($records2)){
        //At the end, i would like to only have the data that is most recent
        $Timer = date('d F', strtotime($stelling['Timer']));



        echo "<p><div style='color:#ED0887'>".$Timer.":</div><a target = '_blank' style='text-decoration:none' href='".$stelling['Source']."'>".$stelling['Title']."</a></p>";

    }}
        $recordscheck+=1;   } // this is totally wrong
```

[image]

**EDIT:**
I've tried this, @noobjs

```
$Timer=0;

$sql1="SELECT 
* 
FROM 
stelling 
LEFT JOIN 
stellingen 
ON 
stelling.ID = stellingen.stelling_id 
WHERE 
stellingen.REGIOID=1
ORDER BY stelling.Timer  LIMIT 5 DESC ;";

$records2 =  mysqli_query($con, $sql1);
printf($records2);
    while ($stelling = mysqli_fetch_assoc($records2)){
        $Timer = date('d F', strtotime($stelling['Timer']));



        echo "<p><div style='color:#ED0887'>".$Timer.":</div><a target = '_blank' style='text-decoration:none' href='".$stelling['Source']."'>".$stelling['Title']."</a></p>";
       }
```

with this error:

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in

**EDIT** for more clarification
Here is some sample data
[image: sample data]

The expected results is:
every page has uses data from a different REGIOID. I expect the page to show data from the table stelling(Table 1). Accordingly to the REGIOID (Table2)

Comment: you can solve it using mysql only. Edit your question showing sample data, table structure and expected results.

Comment: @LelioFaieta Thank you Lelio, I forgot to write expected results.

Comment: use text and not pictures. Btw it is impossible to read a picture like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i understand right:

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  stelling 
LEFT JOIN 
  stellingen 
ON 
  stelling.stellingID = stellingen.stelling_id 
WHERE 
  stellingen.REGIOID=1
ORDER BY stelling.Timer  DESC LIMIT 5 ;
```

Comment: that looks very interesting, im going to try.

Comment: I'm going to put what i tried in addition to myquestion @noobjs

Comment: mysql threw error at DESC position . I edited now i dont get any error by mysql.